# Automating changing the Open XML

Tags: c#, xml, vba, powerpoint, openxml

I'm trying to make an add in that locks graphics in powerpoint. VBA doesn't allow this, but doing so manually is fairly simple, finding the relevant graphic in the XMl data and adding 'No select = 1'.

I'm finding it difficult to find info on the add in automating this, thus eliminating the need to go into the xml data.

I'm assuming it would need to export the 'changed copy, but I simply can't find any info on opening the xml, making changes, then re zipping.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that using VSTO, C# and the Open XML SDK.

VBA on it's own can't edit OOXML. But I've posted a VBA macro set on my blog that allows you to programmatically unzip, edit, and rezip PowerPoint files. It's free to use for your projects, but please don't redistribute it without permission. Here's the link:
[Edit OOXML with VBA - Cool Code](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2021/03/edit-ooxml-with-vba-cool-code/)

Or you can skip the programming and buy the [OfficeOne ShapeLocker](https://www.officeoneonline.com/shapelocker/shapelocker.html) add-in, which already does this.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for answering, your blog has been very helpful. Shapelocker is actually what I'm trying to emulate, just as a personal development thing. Does the macro work with powerpoint? It states for excel on it

Comment: Hi Tom, The macro set I provide is for PowerPoint. Where are you seeing "for Excel"?

Comment: Apologies, I skim read and saw the word excel. Thank you for your time with this!